# emr-dynamodb-connector for Apache Hadoop

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, amazon-emr

I have an EMR and intend to do CRUD operations on dynamo DB as part of my Reducer.

Note I am **not using Hive or Spark** and using Apache Hadoop. Is there any documentation on how to connect to Dynamo DB from my EMR ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[emr-dynamodb-connector](https://github.com/awslabs/emr-dynamodb-connector/tree/master/emr-dynamodb-hadoop/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/dynamodb) is open source library and includes Hadoop classes like `DynamoDBInputFormat`, `DefaultDynamoDBRecordReader` for Reading data(With Parallel scans)  from DynamoDB with Read rate control & 
`DynamoDBOutputFormat` `DefaultDynamoDBRecordWriter` for writing(using BatchWrites API) to DynamoDB with write rate control to avoid throttling.

I don't think there's any more AWS Documentation on this one other than [README](https://github.com/awslabs/emr-dynamodb-connector/blob/master/README.md) of this open source lib.

All EMR clusters should have a pre-build package of this library(except emr-dynamodb-tools) usually @ `/usr/share/aws/emr/ddb/lib/emr-ddb-hadoop.jar` and included in classpath of EMR Hadoop. So, you can just use Hadoop InputFormat and OutputFormat Implementation's from this JAR on your MR Application by setting required config's(including DynamoDB [config's](https://github.com/awslabs/emr-dynamodb-connector/blob/master/emr-dynamodb-hadoop/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/dynamodb/DynamoDBConstants.java)) using [Job](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html#Job_Configuration) Configuration